# Is it possible to add a new Lane or do I need a separate Board

Tags: trello-boards

We have a bunch of DevOps tasks on our Board. We'd like to add Marketing tasks, but not mix them in with DevOps as that would confuse our management of capacity. Our desire is a separate "lane" of items on the same Board.

Comment: Are you referring to Lists? Trello boards hold a set of lists, and each list holds cards...

Answer (score 0):

Trello boards do not offer swim lanes like Jira boards.

Trello operates in vertical columns called Lists.

[Various Power-ups](https://trello.com/power-ups) exist allowing you to add some functionality but nothing related to swim lanes.